# Compute the given complex limit of $\lim_{z \rightarrow i}(\ln|x^2+y^2| + i\arctan(\frac{y}{x}))$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Compute the given complex limit of $\lim_{z \rightarrow i}(\ln|x^2+y^2| + i\arctan(\frac{y}{x}))$

I can see that this reduces to $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,1)} (\ln|x^2+y^2|+ i\arctan(\frac{y}{x}))$.  The real part of the complex expression is $0$, but I'm having trouble understanding what I would do for the complex part.  This seems to be just $\theta$ as the angle of $i$ which would be $\pi/2$, but am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

As you found out yourself the problem is with
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\arctan{y\over x}\ .$$
This limit does not exist, since
$$\lim_{x\to0+}\arctan{1\over x}={\pi\over2},\qquad \lim_{x\to0-}\arctan{1\over x}=-{\pi\over2}\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

No indeterminated form because $$\ln|x^2+y^2| + i\arctan(\frac{y}{x})=\ln|z|^2+i \arg z$$ so when $z\to i$ you have directly $$\lim_{z\to i}(\ln|z|^2+i \arg z)=(\ln 1+i \frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{i\pi}{2}$$